# MySql Query Data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, report, reporting

I am new to SQL so please be kind.  I am able to get all of the information by looking in the database and exporting it to excel.  Once in excel I have to create forumlas to get it all the way I would like it.  If at all possible I would like to just run a query to look at it all.  I have Google'ed around but I can't seem to find something that either makes sense to me or points me in the right direction.

I would think by my searches that there would be some kind of join but again being new to SQL I am grasping at straws.

Given the following sample tables:

Tickets Table:

```
ID    Queue  Owner  Subject            Status    TimeWorked    LastUpdated
001   1      22     need help          Open      20            2012-09-01
002   2      6      internet           Resolved  60            2012-09-03
003   1      24     email not working  Open      15            2012-09-04
```

Users Table:

```
ID    Name
6     Nobody
22    Josh
24    Jon
```

CustomFieldValue Table:

```
Id      ObjectId    CustomField    Content
01      001         1              Bob Inc
02      001         2              0
03      001         3              WaitingOnClient
04      001         4              Remote
05      002         1              ZYC Inc
06      002         2              15
07      002         3              WaitingOnClient
08      002         4              Remote
09      003         1              ACB Inc
10      003         2              0
11      003         3              TimeScheduled
12      003         4              OnSite
```

Queue Table:

```
ID    Name
1     Support
2     Tier2
```

What I would need to be able to do is query to get the results to look like the following

```
ID  Client  Subject   Queue    Owner  Status    Type   BTime CustomStat      LastUpdate NT
001 Bob Inc need help support  Josh   open      Remote 20    WaitingOnClient 2012-09-01 0
001 ZYC Inc internet  Tier2    Nobody Resolved  Remote 60    WaitingOnClient 2012-09-01 15
001 ACB Inc email     support  Jon    open      onsite 15    TimeScheduled   2012-09-01 0
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how did all clients were `Bob Inc`? where the value of queue coming from?

Comment: sorry about that I have updated it.  The Client name should be coming from the CustomFieldValue table.  There are 4 CustomFieldValues 1 through 4.  Value 1 is a company name. Value 2 is the number of minutes we did not bill the client on this issue.  Value 3 is the detailed status and value 4 is the tyep of service.

Comment: ok i got it, check my answer below :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use *inline* `CASE` statement for this, `GROUP_CONCAT` and should be grouped by `ID`. Give this a try.

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN d.CustomeField = 1 THEN d.content ELSE NULL END)) `Client`,
        a.Subject,
        c.Name,
        b.Name Owner,
        a.`Status`,
        GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN d.CustomeField = 4 THEN d.content ELSE NULL END)) `Type`,
        a.TimeWorked,
        GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN d.CustomeField = 3 THEN d.content ELSE NULL END)) `CustomStat`,
        a.LastUpdated,
        GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN d.CustomeField = 2 THEN d.content ELSE NULL END)) `NT`
FROM    tickets a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.owner = b.id
        INNER JOIN queue c
            ON a.queue = c.id
        INNER JOIN  CustomFieldValue d
            ON a.ID = d.ObjectID
 GROUP BY a.ID
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7809/11)

Comment: Why GROUP_CONCAT? I could see this if you expected multiple values for a custom field in a single ticket?

Comment: @JimGarrison because `GROUP_CONCAT` *exclude null values*. [see this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf7db/1). when you click the fiddle above, try [removing `GROUP_CONCAT`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7809/14) and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Would it be possible to only list tickets where the client name was 'bob inc'.